# Find similar integers inside of an ArrayList with Class Method

Tags: java, class, methods, arraylist, subclass

I need to iterate through and ArrayList of objects and look for a variable that has the same value for multiple objects. As the example below, I am looking through an ArrayList, that has a sub-class . All I want to do is find out if a house or condo share the same listing number for this example code. I tried using a double loop, and an enhanced loop with a method (sameListingNum) and am having trouble working it out.

Thank you

```
// main client class
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      ArrayList<House> listings = new ArrayList();

      listings.add(new House(0001, 200000.00));
      listings.add(new House(0201, 200000.00));
      listings.add(new House(0001, 200000.00));
      listings.add(new House(0401, 200000.00));
      listings.add(new House(0031, 200000.00));
      listings.add(new Condo(0401, 200000.00, 4));
      listings.add(new Condo(0001, 120000.00, 3));
      listings.add(new Condo(0301, 220000.00, 2));
      listings.add(new Condo(0001, 130000.00, 3));
      listings.add(new Condo(0201, 130000.00, 3));

      for(House currentHouse: listings)
        System.out.println(currentHouse);
      for(int i=0; i<listings.size()-1; i++)
      {
        for(int j=i+1; j<listings.size(); j++)
        {

        }
      } 

// House Class
public class House 
{
  public int listingNum;
  public double price; 

  public House()
  {
    listingNum = 0; 
    price = 0.00; 
  }  
  public House(int newListingNum, double newPrice)
  {
    listingNum = newListingNum;
    price = newPrice; 
  }  
  public int getListingNum()
  {
    return listingNum;
  }  
  public double getPrice()
  {
    return listingNum; 
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    return ("Listing number: "+listingNum+", Price: "+price);
  }
  public boolean sameListingNum(Object other)
  {
    if(!(other instanceof House))
      return false; 
    else {
      House objHouse = (House)other;
      if(listingNum - objHouse.getListingNum() == 0)
      {
        System.out.println("Same listing numbers: "
        +listingNum+", "+objHouse.getListingNum());
        return true;
      }
      else 
        return false;
    }
  }
}

// Condo Class
public class Condo extends House
{
  public int connectedUnits;

  public Condo()
  {
    super();
    connectedUnits = 0; 
  }
  public Condo(int newListingNum, double newPrice, int newConUnits)
  {
    super(newListingNum, newPrice);
    connectedUnits = newConUnits;
  }

  public double getPrice()
  {
    return price;
  }
  public int getListingNum()
  {
    return listingNum;
  }
  public int getConnectedUnits()
  {
    return connectedUnits; 
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    return super.toString()+", Number of connected unints: "+connectedUnits;
  }

public boolean sameListingNum(Object other)
          {
            if(!(other instanceof House))
              return false; 
            else {
              House objHouse = (House)other;
              if(listingNum - objHouse.getListingNum() == 0)
              {
                System.out.println("Same listing numbers: "
                +listingNum+", "+objHouse.getListingNum());
                return true;
              }
              else 
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group it using a Map of List, like Map> groups.

Then you loop over you list and for each house/condo you put it in the group of the same listing number. At the end you will have a map where for each entry there are all houses/condos with same listing number.

Here a sample:

```
Map<Integer, List<House>> groups = new HashMap<Integer, List<House>>();
for (House house:listings) {
   List<House> group = groups.get(house.getListingNum());
   if (group == null) {
     group = new ArrayList<House>();
     groups.put(house.getListingNum(), group);
   }
   group.add(house);
}

for (Entry<Integer, List<House>> entry:groups.entrySet()) System.out.println("Listing Number "+entry.getKey()+" Houses/condos: "+entry.getValue());
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with using this method (Map of List). Can you apply the sameListingNum method or a modified version of it to accomplish this possibly?

Comment: You want to group Houses and Condos with same listing number right? For example all 0001: [House(0001, 200000.00), House(0001, 200000.00), Condo(0001, 120000.00, 3), Condo(0001, 130000.00, 3)]. All 0031: [House(0031, 200000.00)]. All 0201: [Condo(0201, 130000.00, 3), House(0201, 200000.00)]. And so on...

Comment: Yes, that is the basic intention, but I don not want to sort the ArrayList or modify the ArrayList also. It is a basic iteration and search for similar listingNums. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: With the proposed solution you're not touching the original arrays (only reading it one time). You're are just creating a new data structure (the groups map) where to put the grouped houses/condos.

Comment: Makes sense. My only problem is that this is a class project, and Im not trying to use methods that we haven't covered yet.

Comment: Ah... so you've not covered Maps? only Lists?

Comment: Yes, no Maps. ArrayList, yes. Trying to keep it dumbed down in a sense. Thank you though. I'm going to read on Maps and figure it out now that you brought it into the conversation.

Comment: Question: What would be a simple way to get the count of the entry size, or how many of the entry.getKey() exists. I tried .size(), and it provides the length of the groups array instead of the items in a single group.

Comment: entry.value().size() give you the size of the single group.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the other 2 answers will work alternativly you can implement comparable on the House... eg.

```
public class House implements Comparable<House> 

@Override
public int compareTo(final House o) {
    return listingNum - o.listingNum;
}
```

then inside your main method. Sort the Collection and check to see if the previous row has the same Id all the time.

```
    Collections.sort(listings);

    int previousListing = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (House currentHouse : listings) {
        if (currentHouse.getListingNum() == previousListing){
            System.out.println("Duplicate for " + currentHouse.getListingNum());
        }
        previousListing = currentHouse.getListingNum();
    }
```

take your pick.

Comment: Seems like an easy logic to follow. I will check it out and let you know shortly.

Comment: Works great and the only hitch is that it does not add the initial value that was used for a match variable into the S.O.P(duplicate list). So, it prints all of the duplicates for currentHouse, but negates the initial previousLIsting from the S.O.P(). This prints the total duplicates of n - 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach(House h in listings)
{
if(listings.Exists(p => p.sameListingNum(h)))
{
//do something
}
}
```